# How can I map rating span with input rating value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have dynamic html structure like below example, where in an input field I have rating values.

```
<input class="rating-value"  value=4>
                                    
<div class="rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>

<input class="rating-value"  value=5>
                                    
<div class="rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

I am trying to map it , I have tried below code for map

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var val = parseInt($(".rating-value").val());
        $(".rating>span:nth-child(-n+"+val+")").addClass("rating-checked");
    });
</script>
```

For all rating dom has got value 4, How can I map it input field with same rating div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is only looking at the first `.rating-value` element in the collection. You need to loop through them all, which can be done using `each()`.

From there you need to find the `.rating span` elements related to the current `.rating-value`. In this case it can be done using jQuery's DOM traversal methods, `next()`, `find()` and the `:lt` selector. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.rating-value').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).next('.rating').find(`span:lt(${el.value})`).addClass('rating-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating-checked { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<input class="rating-value" value="4" />
<div class="rating">
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>

<input class="rating-value" value="5" />
<div class="rating">
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

Also note that Font Awesome provides hollow star icons which makes the differentiation easier to understand:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.rating-value').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).next('.rating').find(`span:lt(${el.value})`).toggleClass('far fas');
  });
});
```

```css
.rating-checked { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<input class="rating-value" value="3" />
<div class="rating">
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
</div>

<input class="rating-value" value="1" />
<div class="rating">
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star"></span>
</div>
```